# in QtCreator, how to control the build progress bar with compilation progress

Tags: qt-creator

I'm using **QtCreator** with a **custom toolchain, *make.bat***, under windows.
This *make.bat* makes all the source syncqing and compiling stuff. *It* has many steps, and takes a while.

However, since QtCreator doesn't know anything about what's my *make.bat* doing, the QtCreator building progress bar (the green one on the right bottom corner) doesn't grow little by little. It just changes from 0 to 100%, all of a sudden, when my *make.bat* is finished with errorlevel 0.

**Is there a way a can tell QtCreator the progress of compilation?, so that QtCreator can update de green build progress indicator accordingly**

for example, I could print some text in my *make.bat*, such as:

```
call do_Stuff_1.bat
echo [ 25%%] syncqing...
call do_Stuff_2.bat
echo [ 50%%] parsing hola.cpp...
call do_Stuff_3.bat
echo [ 75%%] compiling...
call do_Stuff_4.bat
echo [100%%] done
```

And QtCreator could parse it (such as it parse the errors and warnings) and update the building progress indicator

Maybe I can create a plugin?

Comment: I don't think Qt Creator is designed to parse custom toolchain outputs. What's wrong with `cmake`?

Comment: This if for our organization. If we start using cmake, I have to instruct all my mates to install cmake a teach them how to use it.